# Google Fonts violates Content Security Policy

Tags: html, css, http, google-font-api, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use Google Fonts and I've never had any problems, but now when I try to add the CSS file on my header I get this error on the console:

Refused to load the stylesheet `'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Whatever'` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"`.

Comment: So you have to change the CSP header you send to allow that resource. If you look at the current setting you can clearly see that styles are limited to the location `self` which most likely does not include `googleapis.com` .

Comment: I've tried modifying it using a meta tag and adding some things I've seen on the internet but I have not been able to solve the this...

Comment: This has nothing to do with meta tags. A `CSP header` is an http header, so part of the protocol, not the content. You send it, be it by purpose or accidentally. Maybe because you use some framework, but we cannot say any more without you posting more details.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm using Meteor JS

Comment: You can easily check that header yourself if you don't believe the error message you see: just open your browsers development console and look at the headers of the basic requests done. They will contain said header. Or you use a network sniffer, comes out the same.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are two things to fix here:

- Use https for the Google fonts link (`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Whatever`)
- Authorize `https://fonts.googleapis.com` in `style-src` directive and `https://fonts.gstatic.com` in `font-src` directive: `"style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com"`

Comment: what is the `data:` for?

Comment: `Allows data: URIs to be used as a content source.`

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#Data

Comment: For others looking at this answer, don't copy over the 'unsafe-inline' as it lowers security for no good reason - it's not needed for the fonts to work. The only reason why it's there is because the OP had it in his original code. Use `style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;`

Comment: @KevinLee If you turn your comment into an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @KevinLee actually it might very well be needed if you inline your styles - witch is very common in react applications for instance.

Answer (score 72):

If you're like me and a little confused because every answer is just saying you need to authorize a URL in a `style-src` directive without showing how to do it, here's the full tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;">
```

Comment: Do the content options you left out like default-src etc lower security, or is it the same as not having a `meta csp` tag in the first place?

Comment: With the `unsafe-inline` attribute allowed, it actually lowers security. The tag can work fine without that, as it makes your app more vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: removed the 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: I just used it as follows: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com">`

Comment: @Owen It's really difficult to find good info on `meta` tag csp's. I am not confident in resolving my font warning at the risk of making everything else less secure:-) My site is a portfolio site, and I don't want to be asked "why you do that??" in an interview:-)

Comment: I was working a whole day on it and found that font-source not working on google fonts but kept that there anyway, I was using for ; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' and it worked perfectly well

Comment: If you are here wondering why this does not work for you, check also HTTP response headers for the HTML file. The response header is set by web server and if it contains stronger condition, it will overrule the `meta` tag.

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple sources that can be given for `Content-Security-Policy`.

Below has clear details, which worked for me.

Depending on which content (css, img, font, media) source error you have, you can change the URL in the below.

```
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
      default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; 
      style-src   'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
      font-src    'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com;
      img-src     'self' data: content:;
      media-src   *;
            "
  />

 <title>My page title</title>

</head>

<body>
  some text
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what does `content:` in your `img-src` do? I've never seen that one before

Answer (score 6):

When working with [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/), the following works perfectly (written in TypeScript):

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { Express } from 'express';
const helmet = require('helmet');
const expressApp: Express = express(); // Create Express instance.

expressApp.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      fontSrc: [
        "'self'", // Default policy for specifiying valid sources for fonts loaded using "@font-face": allow all content coming from origin (without subdomains).
        'https://fonts.gstatic.com' // Google Fonts.
      ],
      styleSrc: [
        "'self'", // Default policy for valid sources for stylesheets: allow all content coming from origin (without subdomains).
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com' // Google Fonts.
      ],
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The combinations above did not work for me. My code is importing the fonts from an `.scss` file like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
```

I added the following:

- `default-src` was set to just `'self'`. This is not necessary, but I wanted everything else locked down. This restriction may trigger errors in the browser console. Adapt as needed. I had to add `wss:` *scheme*, to allow a web socket connection for the Angular debugger.
- `style-src` needed the `'unsafe-inline'` *keyword*. I suspect that it is because the style is packed/minimized.
- `script-src` was also needed with the `'unsafe-inline'` *keyword*. Although I checked the stylesheet downloaded and did not see anything obvious, I think that there must be something there that is considered a script.
- `font-src` needed the `data:` *scheme*. The browser console was giving an error fetching `data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8… (“font-src”)`. This may be something coming from a different place in my Angular code, but it may be useful for someone.

Below the final thing.

```
default-src 'self' wss:;
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';
script-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';
font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com
```

Comment: 'unsafe-inline' is not a good practice to follow as it mitigates XSS attacks.

Comment: True, but if you're restricting the directive to specific URLs that you trust (google in this case), the risk is mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are adding in server.js  then it should be like this

```
let  securityPolicy = `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; ` +
`script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ` +
`img-src 'self' data:  ` +
`style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  ` +
`font-src https://fonts.googleapis.com 'self' data:  ` 


res.header('Content-Security-Policy', res.header('Content-Security-Policy', securityPolicy))
```